# Calling fancybox gallery which has iframe and images

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

what I'm trying to do is to call fancybox gallery which has and iframe and couple images, by clicking a non related div. Everything works fine with image group, but when i try to add an iframe it shows "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."

Below is html and javascript:

```
    <div id="gallery_1">Gallery</div>


     <script>
        $('#gallery_1').click(function (){
        $('#gallery_1').addClass('cur_gal');
        $.fancybox([
          'iframe.html',
          '2.jpg',
          '1.jpg'
        ], 
     {   'padding' : 0,
         'transitionIn' : 'fade',
         'transitionOut' : 'fade',
         'type' : 'image',
         'changeFade' : 1,
         'loop' :false,
         afterClose: function() {
        $('#gallery_1').removeClass('cur_gal');
      }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

I tried to remove 'type' : 'image' , but then the iframe doesn't show.
I've also tried to change type to iframe, but then the images are messed up. The sizes are incorrect, and the scroll bar appears. 
So maybe someone has any ideas how to display iframe and images correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `type` of content individually but you are doing it globally so try modifying your script this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gallery_1').click(function () {
        $('#gallery_1').addClass('cur_gal');
        $.fancybox([{
            href: "iframe.html",
            type: "iframe"
        }, {
            href: "image2.jpg",
            type: "image"
        }, {
            href: "image1.jpg",
            type: "image"
        }], {
            padding: 0,
            // 'transitionIn': 'fade', // for v1.3.4 not compatible
            // 'transitionOut': 'fade', // for v1.3.4 not compatible
            // 'type' : 'image', // sets type of content globally
            changeFade: 1,
            loop: false,
            afterClose: function () {
                $('#gallery_1').removeClass('cur_gal');
            }
        });
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xwZt/)**

**EDIT** : you can also change this lines

```
$('#gallery_1').click(function () {
    $('#gallery_1').addClass('cur_gal');
```

into this

```
$('#gallery_1').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('cur_gal');
```